# How can I pass the different arguments in same components (in Angular)?

Tags: angular, overloading

I define a sub components, and in main components.html, I want to make like this..

```html
<div>
<app-A></app-A>  <!--first component-->
<app-A></app-A>  <!--second component-->
<app-A></app-A>  <!--third component-->
<app-A></app-A>  <!--fourth component-->
</div>
```

I want to keep the same structure in four components, but I want 'text' in structure is different in each components. What I want is similar in Java Overloading.. it is possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass an input to the component like the below ([check here](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)) :

So you would do something like this:

```
<div>
    <app-A name="first-component"></app-A>  <!--first component-->
    <app-A name="second-component"></app-A>  <!--second component-->
    <app-A name="third-component"></app-A>  <!--third component-->
    <app-A name="fourth-component"></app-A>  <!--fourth component-->
</div>
```

and then inside you `app-A` component you need to read the `name` attribute like this

```
@Input() name = ''; // decorate the property with @Input()
```

and inside the Html you could do:

```
<div *ngIf="name==='first-component'">do whatever you want</div>
....
```

Comment: @shinbian11 If you find my answer useful you can react to it and mark it as useful or as the solution!